# My scipy.misc module appears to be missing imsave

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-3.3

I open the python3 interpreter and type

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave
```

with the result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imsave'
```

Has the name changed? It works fine in python2 but I would rather not migrate backwards so to speak.

I have python 3.3.1 on Lubuntu 13.04 with all the modules downloaded from the default repositories. Scipy is installed and `print(scipy.misc.__doc__)` shows that `imsave` should be there.

EDIT:

`scipy.__version__` gives 0.11.0

`from scipy.misc import imsave` gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name imsave
```

Comment: what is `scipy.__version__` and what does `from scipy.misc import imsave` do?  For that matter, what if you change `scipt.misc.imsave` to `scipy.misc.imsave`?

Comment: I've added the results and fixed the spelling mistake.

Comment: `scipy.misc.imsave` is from `pilutils` which depends on `PIL`.  Do you have `PIL` installed?  If so, it's probably worth upgrading `scipy`, which is at `0.13.0` now.  Even if the upgrade isn't necessary, perhaps the re-installation is.

Comment: newer duplicate question/answer, but with references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253092

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imsave` has been deprecated in newer Scipy versions.

Change your code to:

```
import imageio
imageio.imwrite('filename.jpg', array)
```

Answer (score 16):

Or `pip install pillow` in order to install a new PIL implementation. This works well in Python 3.4.

Comment: pillow needs some libraries as well, it won't necessarily work if you can't install OS packages. (--user)

Comment: I pip installed pillow without errors on windows 10 for python 3.7 (in a virtual environment).    I still get `'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imsave'`

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the Ubuntu package [`python3-imaging`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python3-imaging).  This packages provides PIL (the Python Imaging Library).  PIL is required by `imsave` (and other `im*` functions in `scipy.misc`).

Comment: Thankyou, after askewchan's comment I was trying to find a package that would work happily with python3 but hadn't time to do a proper search.

Comment: Package no longer exists?

Comment: Try the package [`python-pil`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+package/python-pil).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the answers to this question didn't help. I solved it by installing a previous version of scipy:

```
pip3 install scipy==0.17.0
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 'Failed to build wheel for scipy.'

Answer (score 0):

The function was deprecated in `1.2.0` as noted in a previous version of the documentation. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

The [`1.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.1.0/) version of the library was the last version to have this function enabled which can be installed with

```
pip3 install scipy==1.1.0
```

**Note**: This version of the code was released on May 6, 2018