# 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imsave'

Tags: python, scipy

When i try to save an image using Scipy.misc.imsave('path',image).

I got this Error : module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute.

I am working on Ubuntu 17.10 and i have both pillow and scipy installed.
Can you help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.misc module has no attribute imread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345790/scipy-misc-module-has-no-attribute-imread)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`scipy.misc.imsave` [has been deprecated since SciPy 1.0](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.1.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes), and was removed in SciPy 1.2.

They suggest using `imageio.imwrite` (from the [`imageio`](https://pypi.org/project/imageio/) library) instead.

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to Python but I've been developing for 15 years, I just don't understand how the old ```scipy.misc.imsave``` got it's image input to save? ```imageio.imwrite``` takes 2 parameters, path and image, but ```scipy.misc.imsave``` only takes one which is the path is it inherited or something?

Comment: @JayCroghan `scipy.misc.imsave()`'s signature was `scipy.misc.imsave(name, arr, format=None)`, so it does indeed take at least two parameters.

Comment: That's what the docs said, but in the project I downloaded from GitHub it'